# HTTP File Upload with CORS and Angular

Tags: php, angular, cors, lumen

I am trying to generate a POST/PUT request where I upload a file to a URL.
The backend script is in PHP using Lumen/Laravel 5.4; for front-end, I am using Angular 7 with **HttpClient** to send the file via `formdata`.

Now if I send any <s>normal data (simple text not file) via POST it succeeds, but if I upload a file</s> request I get the following error:

- **IN FIREFOX**: no POST request is generated after pre-flight (`OPTIONS`) request and shows a generic CORS error:

  `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://storage.local/upload. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]`
- **IN CHROME**: POST request is generated but response is not shown, and throws `net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED`

**Angular Code:**

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append("material", mmfile);
return this.http.post(environment.storage_server, form, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().append("authorization", token),
}).subscribe( event => {
  console.log(event)
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
}, () =>{
  console.log("done");
})
```

**Headers in PHP Script:**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS")
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Host, Accept-Encoding, Referer, Accept, Content-Disposition, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description")
header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
```

Regards

PS: I am writing after trying to solve this for 6 hours, so I may have missed a few things. Feel free to edit or ask for any details.

**EDIT:**

Headers returned in `OPTIONS`

```
    HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 11 Dec 2018 12:02:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: AUTHORIZATION
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF
```

Headers sent on `OPTIONS`:

```
Host: storage.local
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Verify that the server-side part you have shown above actually answers to OPTIONS requests as well. Depending in how you set up your routing, that must not necessarily be the case. If it isn’t, and it goes into some other branch, the OPTIONS request might still get answered, but without those CORS-related headers being properly set.

Comment: @misorude I added the OPTIONS request's returned headers. So to answer your query, yep it does reply.

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the headers like that if you're using Lumen. Have a look at https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: Had the same error with that, so I opted this, so that I can at least debug.

Comment: Does look weird, that you would get `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, when you explicitly set `$request->header("Origin")` for that one? The browser should send the Origin with the OPTIONS request already, so it is weird if your system would not detect that correctly, and respond with `*` instead.

Comment: @misorude sorry copied wrong code. Its `*`. @MatthewDaly I used that CORS library but file uploads still fail but normal ones work though.

Comment: Can you check the request headers your browser sends with the OPTIONS request as well? Maybe there’s an additional one in there not currently allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers?

Comment: @misorude I have updated the OPTIONS responses (using the CORS library as advised by @MatthewDaly) and added OPTIONS request header

Comment: You are sending several [forbidden request headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name), but say only `AUTHORIZATION` was allowed …

Comment: @misorude so I should add them in allowed header... All of the forbidden ones?